# Mysql : Aggregation function is not working without group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregation

I am using following query

```
SELECT count(*) as num,id,page_name FROM project_page where p_id = '256'
```

this query is running fine on mysql version 5.1.49-3 and giving error on mysql 5.0.32-Debian_7etch8-log
On both server i have exactly same database.

error message

`#1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

How do i run the above query on 5.0.31 without any error

Please help.

Comment: Your query is broken. MySQL just runs it anyway and gives indeterminate results, but pretty much any other database would give you an error message. What are you trying to do?

Comment: but without group by my queries are working on the 5.1.49

Comment: Define "working". On MySQL you get indeterminate results. Please read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: I mean i ma getting result from above query when i am using this query in 5.1.49 version. Actually i am little week in this can you please tell why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Add 
`... GROUP BY num, id, page_name`

Comment: If `id` is a unique identifier per row, then this probably won't do what the OP wants. Though it's not clear what he wants because he "forgot" to write that.

Comment: Even if you don't need to group by, just group by id (primary key) and it worked for me.